# How can I replace root / filesystem with another filesystem?

Tags: mount, init, initramfs, initrd, root-filesystem

When the Linux kernel starts up, it uses initrd as the root / filesystem, then replaces that with a filesystem partition in fstab.

Based on a test in an early init script, I want to replace that root / filesystem with another filesystem partition. How to do that?

Comment: Are you asking to create a dual boot?

Comment: @ryekayo no, not dual boot. Dual boot is a modification of boot loader. I'm not modifying the boot loader.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to go initrd → root #1 → root #2? This isn't possible. But you can modify the content of the initrd and go initrd → root #2. (Are you sure it's an initrd and not an initramfs? Most distributions have switched to initramfs, even though the image file may still be called `initrd`; the principle is the same but the mechanics are a little different.) What tests do you need to make to determine the location of the root filesystem?

Comment: Here's an alternative in case you can't do it inside initrd: list all your possible roots as separate boot options in grub.conf, then in an init script use `grub-reboot n` to choose one of them if the desired root isn't currently mounted. http://superuser.com/a/290458/264506 has some details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark. Unfortunately the machine is Arm architecture and doesn't use grub.

Comment: If you don't have a strong requirement to use Linux, you might consider FreeBSD - it has a mechanism called "reroot", which does exactly that and is rather trivial from the user point of view: just tell the kernel where the new rootfs is and then do "reboot -r"; see EXAMPLES section at http://man.freebsd.org/reboot.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but still came up in Google. if you stumble on this, look at pivot_root
https://linux.die.net/man/8/pivot_root

Comment: Why do.you want to do this instead of specifying the root filesystem you want using root=xxx kernel argument? So the early init will mount that filesystem and pivot root to that